# Error The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Color?'

Tags: flutter

There is my code :
The StreamBuilder has an error

> Error The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter
> type 'Color?

```
body: Center(
          child: StreamBuilder(
            stream: bloc.stateStream,
            initialData: Colors.amber,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              return AnimatedContainer(
                duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
                color: snapshot.data,
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: StreamBuilder(
            stream: bloc.stateStream,
            initialData: Colors.amber,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              return AnimatedContainer(
                duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
                color: snapshot.data,
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
}
```

Comment: You are assigning type Object to color property, the color property expects the value of type Color. Is your stateStream returns color?

Comment: Yes, I want to return the color

Comment: Could you please update your code with BLoC?

Comment: You can format your code for better readability.

Comment: don't directly pass: color: snapshot.data, instead use variable of color before return statement and then use in color property.

Comment: this is because color: property trying to read data from snapshot.data which is actually dynamic object and not color instance initially.

Answer (score 1):

Your getting the error because the `snapshot` is of type `AsyncSnapshot<Object?>` and when you set the color to `snapshot.data`, the type `Object`, there's a type mismatch since the color should be of type `Color`.

You can fix the error by specifying the type of stream your StreamBuilder is using like below:

```dart
    body: Center(
              child: StreamBuilder<Color>( //Add <Color> after StreamBuilder
                stream: bloc.stateStream,
                initialData: Colors.amber,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  return AnimatedContainer(
                    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                    width: 100,
                    height: 100,
                    color: snapshot.data,
                  );
                },
              ),
    ),
```